# Read an XML standard config file selected from console

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I created a CLI application which actually uses the standard config `app.Config` file.

In this file I put some subsections, like

```
 <typicsTable>
    <mainSettings>
      <add key="sheetNumber" value="1"/>
      <add key="firstDataRow" value="2"/>
    </mainSettings>
 </typicsTable>
```

I actually read these settings with

```
NameValueCollection TypicsConversionTableSettings = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("typicsTable/mainSettings");

int ctSheetNumber =     Int32.Parse(TypicsConversionTableSettings["sheetNumber"]);
int ctFirstDataRow =    Int32.Parse(TypicsConversionTableSettings["firstDataRow"]);
```

Everything works fine in this way.

What I want to do now is

1) I want different config files with custom names (i.e. `test1.config` , `test2.config`) and take via CLI the right config file;

2) switch to a less ".net config file", and take data from a standard XML file.

I'm now focusing on the point 1, I tried different attempts, I used

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"C:\folderTest\conf1.config";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

But I absolutely don't get how to read sections AND subsections in the file. How can I do that?

Comment: Your last <typicsTable> has a typo should be </typicsTable> to close it.

Comment: You have several options. Option A) If you stick to use `Configuration` and `ConfigurationManager` classes in order retrieve a specific section from an arbitrary config then you can derive from the `ConfigurationSection` class to specify arbitrary logic for settings retrieval. [Further info](http://joelabrahamsson.com/creating-a-custom-configuration-section-in-net/) Option B) Use Linq to XML to retrieve data from any arbitrary xml with [Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-retrieve-a-single-child-element-linq-to-xml)

Comment: very clean and plain explanation for ConfigurationManager :) thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class that is going to help you, I believe, is **System.Xml.Linq**.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

So Part 1 would be load the file into an XElement:

```
XElement xConfig = XElement.Load("app.simulated.config");
```

Here's a quick demo of how you can iterate through everything and also find a single element using a matching condition.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Iterating the config file values and attributes...");
        Console.WriteLine("==================================================");
        XElement xConfig = XElement.Load("app.simulated.config");
        foreach (var element in xConfig.DescendantsAndSelf())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element.Name);
            foreach (var attribute in element.Attributes())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + attribute.Name + "," + attribute.Value);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Finding a value using matching conditions.");
        Console.WriteLine("==========================================");

        XElement xel =
            xConfig
            .DescendantsAndSelf()
            .FirstOrDefault(match => 
                (match.Attribute("key") != null) && 
                (match.Attribute("key").Value == "sheetNumber"));

        Console.WriteLine(
            "The value of 'sheetNumber' is " +
            xel.Attribute("value").Value
         );

        // Pause
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

[image: Console Output]

[Clone or Download](https://github.com/IVSoftware/app-simulated-config.git) this example from GitHub.

Comment: Yes, thanks! it's exactly what I need, my only question would be how to get a single element instead of looping on that, but looking in the System.Linq library I should find the answer...

Comment: There! That's how you use matching conditions to find something in a file like that.